# FOR LOOP in Angular Service NOT Working - While Loop Works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, service

I've worked around this problem with a while loop
but thought I'd explain it here - because it seems odd

I tried iterating through a string in a service using a for loop, but cannot get it to work

When service defined like this

```
.service('xtratxt', function()
 {
   var x = 0;
   var a = "";

   this.convert = function(srctxt)
   {
     this.a = "";
     this.x = 0;
     for (this.x=0; this.x++; this.x<srctxt.length)
     {
       this.a = ans + "X";
     }
     return ans;
   };
 })
```

if I call this in my controller with

```
$scope.newvalu = xtratxt.convert("Hello");
```

I should get back a string of X's   Eg XXXXX
Instead I get an empty string ""

If I change to a while loop - no problems works a treat

Anyone know why ?

I get no errors in the console either.
AFAIK it doesn't seem to enter the for loop at all

Comment: your for loop isnt correctly written you need `this.x++` to be at the end and the `this.x<srctext.length` to be in the middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.convert = function (srctxt) {
    var a = "", x = 0, ans = '';
    for (x = 0; x < srctxt.length; x++) {
        ans += "X";
    }
    return ans;
};
```

**Shorter version**

```
var str = 'abcde';
str.replace(/\w/gi, 'X');
```

Comment: But that's not the routine I was really after - just a much shortened one for ease of clearing up where my mistake was .. thanks again